# Why should we use the 'override' key word in Kotlin for abstact class members?

Tags: class, oop, kotlin, abstract

If the base class has an abstract method or property, than these members must be overriden in the child class. The documentation says that i must use key word '**override**' every time for such members, because i must implement methods or initialize properties in the child class. For example:

```
abstract class Dwelling {
    abstract val buildingMaterial: String

    abstract fun hasRoom() : Boolean
}

class RoundHut : Dwelling() {
    override val buildingMaterial = "Stone"

    override fun hasRoom() : Boolean {
         return true
    }
}
```

If an abstract method and a property must be overriden and implemented in child class any way (and compiler know this), than why we should write 'override' key word every time?

Comment: Good point, the language could have been designed differently. Note that in some languages, the 'abstract' keyword is called 'mustoverride'. Also, other languages also require override for implementing abstract members, so I guess the language designers decided to follow that pattern.

Comment: Note that, if the base class is not yours, the maker of the base class gains the freedom of switching to virtual, providing a default implementation. If your child class wouldn't use the override keyword, that would be a breaking change.

Comment: yeah, that's right. Another reason that the maker of the base class can turn the abstract method to a regular one with its own implemented logic and than my class would need some fixes.Thanks.

Comment: This also improves readability, you can have few overridden methods and few own methods in one class and then you can easily know which one comes from which place. Next reason beside from readability is that override has other interesting feature behind it "A member marked override is itself open, i.e. it may be overridden in subclasses. If you want to prohibit re-overriding, use final:"

Comment: "Explicit is better then implicit" (c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you find yourself reading and understanding the implementing class, you have the explicit information that you're currently investigating an overridden one as it's explicitly marked as such. Kotlin likes to make things explicit and the documentation states

> [...] we stick to making things explicit in Kotlin. So, Kotlin requires explicit modifiers for overridable members (we call them open) and for overrides

Java has an `@Override` annotation that is optional and not used by everyone although it has been considered a best practice (even as per [Effective Java](https://github.com/mgp/book-notes/blob/master/effective-java-2nd-edition.markdown#item-36-consistently-use-the-override-annotation)). Kotlin goes one step further by making it a compiler-enforced requirement.